# solving similar triangle problems

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, word-problem

Brett needs to support a radio tower with guy wires. Each guy wire must run from the top of the tower to its own anchor 9.00 m from the base of the tower. When the tower casts a shadow that is 9.00 m long, Brett’s shadow is 0.60 m long. Brett is 1.85 m tall. What is the length of each guy wire that Brett needs?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Can you show us what you tried and where exactly you are stuck

Comment: The height of tower is $\frac{9}{0.6}\times 1.85=27.75$ m. Now you have a right triangle with sides $27.75$ and $9$, can you find the length of wire now?